JUnit tests take long time to instantiate/execute in IntelliJ
Intellij Version : IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.6 (Ultimate Edition
Java Version : 11
Project type : Gradle
Intellij Compiler Settings:

Build Project Automatically is checked
Compile independent modules in parallel is checked
Tried both javac and eclipse as compilers

When I try to run a JUnit test, Intellij starts the Gradle daemon and builds the whole project. This happens every time I try to run a simple unit test. Is there any way to skip the Gradle build steps? It otherwise takes ~1 minute to run a 2 sec JUnit test.

Consider configuring IntelliJ to compile and run the tests itself, instead of delegating this to Gradle. Under Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle, set "Build and run using"  and "Run tests using" to IntelliJ IDEA.
